# How to query DataSets using LINQ and ouput in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

**I have two classes in WCF Service:**

```
[DataContract]
public class item
{
    [DataMember]
    public string categoryid
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }       
}
```

I am fetching data from DataSets using LINQ:

```
public List<Employee> GetCities()
{ 
    var em = ((from DataRow dr in ds.Tables["City"].Rows
        select new
        {
            Id = dr["intCityId"].ToString(),
            Name = dr["strTitle"].ToString()                          
        }).Select(x => new Employee() { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name}).ToList());
}
```

Now I'm getting JSON data by return this value.
Also I've got values from the item class also but now I want to convert the list data into JSON format just like following::

```
{"content":{"em" :[{ "id" : "1","Name" : "name"},{ "id" : "2","Name" : "name2"}],
"item":[{"category":"Sports","Title":"Football"},{"category":"Sports1","Title":"Football2"}]}}
```

Meaning I want to merge these two classes result as one but in above format which is clean JSON format

Please Help...

Comment: Have you tried [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)?

Comment: This is not LINQ to SQL - your title + tags are misleading. You are using datasets. Also it is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have mentioned in last lines that i want to merge two list/dataset values in json format and i also give an example that what i want...

Comment: jrummell i have tried JavaScriptSerializer but it didnt help me much..
@DannyVarod Thanks for Editing the Title...

Comment: Nothing Worked till now but still thank u guys for answering very fastly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also serialize anonymous objects to JSON.

Example:

```
var cities  = GetCities();
var employees = GetEmployees();
return new JsonResult { Data = new { Content = new { Employees = employees, Cities = cities } } };
```

Comment: Bertl please will you explain what do you want to say or do..
act. i m new in this so will you explain this to me..

Comment: The `JsonResult` object has a property called `Data` and everything within it will be serialized to JSON. Now what you wanted to serialize are two arrays contained within an object called `"Content"`. In order to create the `"Content"` part in JSON we need to add an equivalent in C#. For this I created an [anonymous object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) which itself contains the two lists. The resulting object is then assigned as another anonymous object to `JsonResult.Data`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new object content that contains a list of employee and a list of item. Populate the object and serialize it via JSON serializer.

Comment: You mean i need a class that contains List of employee and item